# 1dB beamwidth of half wave dipole antenna

Tags: antenna

Could anyone kindly help me out with this assignment question? 
"*Derive the mathematical formula for the 1-dB beam-width of a center-fed half-wave dipole antenna.*"

Comment: Do you have a formula for the E field strength as a function of azimuth angle?

Answer (score 1):

1) Find the field strength at the center of the beam, or the maximum field strength.

2) Apply a 1 dB reduction to that field strength and find the result

3) Solve the radiation pattern to find the angle off-center which produces that field strength.

Since you "have complete knowledge of ... its radiation pattern", all three steps should be straightforward.

4) Multiply by 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will get back to you soon after getting the results.